# Dual Channel Recordings

Tags: twilio, sip, amazon-transcribe

I have a twilio sip trunk that's recording calls on a dual channel. However, as I'd like to transcribe offline - the solution I'm using (i.e. AWS transcriber) would like me to specify some details on the recording channels. Specifically, I need to specify which channel has the speech from the agent and which one has the customer's speech... Therefore my question is, among both channels (i.e. channel 1 and channel 2) which one is for the agent and which one is for the customer?

Any insights are highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```json
"channels": [ "customer", "others" ]
```

The order of channels in the recording (inbound calls) is the 1st one for the customer and 2nd one for the agent

Link to official docs - https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/insights/enable-dual-channel-recordings#the-building-blocks